# Separate Display for Start date and End date using Date module

Tags: theming, datetime

I have a date field which collects both start date and end date. I would like to display start date and end date as seprate in the display.

I don't see any options in the display page. I am sure I am missing some basic setting. Any ideas?

**Note :** I am not using views and I would like to do it using the field display options only.

Answer (score 0):

There a few options. If you're comfortable with code you could add a preprocess hook to duplicate the date field and manipulate its configurations. That is a little heavy-handed and hard to maintain.

With the Panels suite of modules (particularly panelizer module) you get the ability to do things like take over entity view modes. Then you can place fields as "panes" as many times as you want with different configurations.